# Please show me a 'rounded corners button' whose background changes color when pressed & resumes original color when released in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I know how to change the background color of a regular button upon on_press and on_release, but with a rounded corners button, there is an issue with the background color of the regular button needing to be transparent. I want the background color of the rounded button to change color only within the rounded rectangle of the button.

When I use the code below, I no longer have the button responding graphically:

```
self.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Invisible background color to regular button
self.background_normal = ''
```

This must certainly be simple, but I can't find the solution via Google. There are faulty or incomplete examples.

Here is the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle

kivy.require('2.0.0')


class RoundedCornerButton(Button):
    background_color = ListProperty((0.5, .5, .5, .5))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RoundedCornerButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.draw()
        self.text = 'test'
        self.size_hint = (0.05, 0.05)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

    def update_shape(self, *args):
        self.shape.pos = self.pos
        self.shape.size = self.size

    def on_background_color(self, *args):
        self.shape_color.rgba = self.background_color

    def draw(self, *args):
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.shape_color = Color(rgba=(0.5, .5, .5, .5))
            self.shape = RoundedRectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, radius=[15])
            self.bind(pos=self.update_shape, size=self.update_shape)

    def on_press(self, *args):
        self.background_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)

    def on_release(self, *arg):
        self.background_color = (0.5, .5, .5, .5)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RoundedCornerButton()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with it and found the solution.
Here is the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, RoundedRectangle

kivy.require('2.0.0')


class RoundedButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RoundedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)  # Invisible background color to regular button
        self.background_normal = ''

        with self.canvas.before:
            self.shape_color = Color(rgba=(0.5, .5, .5, .5))
            self.shape = RoundedRectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, radius=[15])
            self.bind(pos=self.update_shape, size=self.update_shape)

        self.text = 'test'
        self.size_hint = (0.05, 0.05)
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

    def update_shape(self, *args):
        self.shape.pos = self.pos
        self.shape.size = self.size

    def on_press(self, *args):
        self.shape_color.rgba = (0, 0, 1, 1)
        print('pressed')

    def on_release(self, *arg):
        self.shape_color.rgba = (0.5, .5, .5, .5)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RoundedButton()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: It is not perfect button because it is like square button and it can be pressed also by pressing on corners outside it.If you have any solution too this problem please share.I want a permanent solution for all types of shapes.

Comment: @John Anderson Can you shed some light on Abhay Kumar's comment above?